# mysql select this or that?

Tags: php, mysql

On page load mysql query:

```
$today = date('D, d M, Y');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM programs WHERE singleday = '$today' AND city = 'New York'";
```

And I have a calender, while changing the date I want to pick data and display according to date:

```
<form method="post">
  <input align="center" type="text" id="picker" 
    onchange="this.form.submit()" name="picker" size="30"/>
</form>
```

and

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM programs 
  WHERE singleday = '$_POST[picker]' AND city = 'New York'";
```

So what I need is while going to New York want to show today's data and while changing the calendar date show data on the particular date, on the same page.

Please help

Comment: Please take some care into choosing a descriptive title, formatting your code and phrasing your problem. I have tried to make sense of what you are saying, but am having a pretty hard time doing so. If you phrase your problem in such a way that others understand it within a matter of seconds, you will receive higher quality answers.

Comment: btw, if you checked if $_POST['picker'] existed, then you could use either of the sql statements. you can check it exists with isset

Comment: Is this homework? I've seen a few questions around this vague use case lately.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 obvious options:

1. when the date changes, it
   posts the form and reloads the whole
   page.
2. have the date part in an
   iframe, so it only reloads the date
   part, but works like option 1
   essentially
3. ajax, so the date changes,
   triggers a call to send back data
   you load into a defined area

.

Comment: To which option? Im guessing the ajax one.. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647904/how-to-call-multiple-ajax-functions-to-php-without-repeating-code/5647934#5647934

Answer (score 0):

> You can't always get what you want [...] but sometimes you get what you need --Mick Jagger

See: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)
For explanation on SQL-injections.

**You have a SQL-injection hole in the following code**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM programs 
  WHERE singleday = '$_POST[picker]' AND city = 'New York'";
```

Change it to:

```
$mydate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[picker]);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM programs 
  WHERE singleday = '$mydate' AND city = 'New York'";
//                  ^       ^ these quotes must be there to be protected.
```